# Elemento droppable accept y scope diferencias

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

En el siguente codigo, tengo 4 elementos Droppable que aceptan solo algunos elementos Draggable.

La aceptacion de 2 de estos elementos se declara con 'scope' y en los otros 2 se declara con 'accept'.

Que diferencia tiene hacerlo de una u otra forma?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
      <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      
      <style>
         .wrap {
            display: table-row-group;
         }
         #japanpeople,#indiapeople, #javatutorial,#springtutorial { 
            width: 120px; height: 70px; padding: 0.5em; float: left;
            margin: 0px 5px 10px 0; 
         }
         
         #japan,#india,#java,#spring { 
            width: 140px; height: 100px;padding: 0.5em; float: left; 
            margin: 10px;  
         }
      </style>

      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#japanpeople" ).draggable();
            $( "#indiapeople" ).draggable();

            $( "#japan" ).droppable({
               accept: "#japanpeople",
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( this )
                  .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                  .find( "p" )
                  .html( "Dropped!" );
               }
            });
    
            $( "#india" ).droppable({
               accept: "#indiapeople",
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( this )
                  .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                  .find( "p" )
                  .html( "Dropped!" );
               }
            });

            $( "#javatutorial" ).draggable({scope : "java"});
            $( "#springtutorial" ).draggable({scope : "spring"});
    
            $( "#java" ).droppable({
               scope: "java",
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( this )
                  .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                  .find( "p" )
                  .html( "Dropped!" );
               }
            });
    
            $( "#spring" ).droppable({
               scope: "spring",
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( this )
                  .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                  .find( "p" )
                  .html( "Dropped!" );
               }
            }); 
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <div class = "wrap" >
         <div id = "japanpeople" class = "ui-widget-content">
            <p>People to be dropped to Japan</p>
         </div>

         <div id = "indiapeople" class = "ui-widget-content">
            <p>People to be dropped to India</p>
         </div>

         <div id = "japan" class = "ui-widget-header">
            <p>Japan</p>
         </div>

         <div id = "india" class = "ui-widget-header">
            <p>India</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr/>
         
      <div class = "wrap" >
         <div id = "javatutorial" class = "ui-widget-content">
            <p>People who want to learn Java</p>
         </div>
         <div id = "springtutorial" class = "ui-widget-content">
            <p>People who want to learn Spring</p>
         </div>
         <div id = "java" class = "ui-widget-header">
            <p>Java</p>
         </div>

         <div id = "spring" class = "ui-widget-header">
            <p>Spring</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se utiliza `accept` cuando quieres limitar solo los elementos que tengan el selector especificado en la propiedad `accept`:

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".elemento" ).draggable();

    $( "#dropable-contentainer" ).droppable({
       accept: ".wrap .inner-wrap .elemento",
       drop: function( event, ui ) {
         alert("aceptado!");
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.elemento { 
  width: 120px; height: 70px; padding: 0.5em; float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 0; 
}
#dropable-contentainer
{
  background:blue;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:400px;
}
```

```html
<title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
   rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         
<div class = "wrap" >
  <div class="inner-wrap">
     <div class = "ui-widget-header elemento">
        <p>elemento 1</p>
     </div>
  </div>


   <div class = "ui-widget-header elemento">
      <p>elemento 2</p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="dropable-contentainer">
   </div>
</div>
<hr/>
```

Fijate como solo acepta el elemento que cumple con el selector `.wrap .inner-wrap .elemento`. Aunque hay 2 elementos con la clase `.elemento`, solo 1 cumple con el selector.

`scope` se utiliza cuando quieres hacerlo por categoria. Todos los elementos que hayan sido asignado como draggable con el scope asignado son habiles para el drop sobre el elemento droppable:

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".elemento1" ).draggable({scope: "solo-elemento-1" });
    $( ".elemento2" ).draggable({scope: "solo-elemento-2" })

    $( "#dropable-contentainer" ).droppable({
       scope: "solo-elemento-1",
       drop: function( event, ui ) {
         alert("aceptado!");
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.elemento1, .elemento2 { 
  width: 120px; height: 70px; padding: 0.5em; float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 0; 
}
#dropable-contentainer
{
  background:blue;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-left:400px;
}
```

```html
<title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
   rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         
<div class = "wrap" >
  <div class="inner-wrap">
     <div class = "ui-widget-header elemento1">
        <p>elemento 1</p>
     </div>
  </div>


   <div class = "ui-widget-header elemento2">
      <p>elemento 2</p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="dropable-contentainer">
   </div>
</div>
<hr/>
```

Solo en el elemento con el scope solo-elemento-1 puede ser aceptado en el contenedor.

Comment: Gracias por la explicacion y ejemplos.

Por lo que veo el resultado al final es el mismo, tanto uno como otro logran el mismo objetivo de dividir en grupos los elementos droppable/draggable.